# Trying to make ROI column into a float

Tags: python, pandas

ROI column:

[image]

I tried this, which has worked for profit column which had $ sign along with parenthesis to describe loss:

```
df['ROI'] = df['ROI'].str.replace('%','').str.replace('-', '-\\1').astype('float')
```

Getting this error now:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-\\111.41'
```

Comment: a back slash is also a string character, you can not have that either if you are wanting to convert the column into a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to replace the backslash, you just need to change the second `replace`:

```py
df["ROI_updated"] = df.ROI.str.replace(r"%", "", regex=True).str.replace("-\\\\", "-", regex=True).astype(float) / 100

>>> df
        ROI  ROI_updated
0    23.20%       0.2320
1  -\111.41      -1.1141
```